# Searching New York civil litigation case law

Tags: new-york-state, legal-research, case-law, civil-judgment, legal-citation

Are civil cases litigated in the state of New York between private businesses back in the 1980s accessible to the general public somewhere somehow, either free or behind a paywall?

Say I know that a certain music producer and a certain artist had their time in a New York courtroom in 198x. How do I find the decision?

Comment: clerk of the court, but you might need a case number

Comment: @Trish Neither the case number nor specific court is known. Just the names and some case-specific keywords.

Comment: that complicates things, you might need to pay a legal research office or find the party/their lawyer and try to find out if they still know or have data

Comment: Appellate court rulings of widely available from a variety of databases. Trial court orders on substantive legal issues are selectively reported by commercial databases. For all else you need to get information from the court system itself.